# Windows Accounts and processes exploitation

Tags: windows, security, process

Part 1- Do all processes and executables in Windows require an account run and manage them. I was reading how the System account manages the core processes of the OS while service accounts and User accounts manage applications.

Part 2- Do applications or processes that are exploited by any means such as buffer overflow for example and a hacker receives a shell from the exploitation will the shell be under the priveleges of the account that was running the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand your first question, but yes all the processes have a owner (so a 'user' account in some way...). System is just a particular user in Windows who can basically do anything.

Given a process X which has been run by USER_A, if you're USER_B and exploit the process X with a buffer overflow (or whatever), by controlling this process, you will be able to do everything USER_A can do, so if you launch a shell through the process X, you will have the rights of USER_A in this shell.

Comment: Just to complicate things, the owner of the process isn't necessarily the same as the security context the process is running in.  (They'll be the same in most cases, though.)